# Best way to attach objects/armor to cloth

Tags: cloth-simulation

I have a skirt with a cloth sim on it, and some pieces of armor. The top loop of the cloth is pinned to a rigged character, which I have animated to do a walk cycle. I want the armor to sort of hang from the cloth and follow it, but at the same time keep its shape.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an empty and parent it to the cloth mesh using the "3 vertex" option, so that the empty will follow the average position of three selected vertices of the cloth mesh. Then you can add an armature and set a copy location constraint to the armor bone, pointing at the empty.

[image]

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Now I just need to figure out how to get my cloth sims to stop jittering..