# How to attach an object to a cloth simulation

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, physics, cloth-simulation

I created a rope and added a cloth simulation to it, it works as it should.
But now I need this rope to attach with another object. Let's say I have a ring and I inserted this rope into the hole of the ring. When starting the animation, the rope goes through the ring.
Questions:

1. How do I tie a rope to this ring? I used a hook and it didn't work.
2. How to make the ring move on the rope when cloth simulation, that is, so that the rope affects this ring and it moves together in the rope

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192863/best-way-to-attach-objects-armor-to-cloth/192923#192923

Comment: Help me, I tied a piece of rope to a null object, with normal movement everything works, but when I run the cloth simulation, then my rope does not hold on to the null object and dangles by itself

Comment: So, I sort of succeeded, I added a bone, tied it to a zero object, and tied the zero object to a piece of the rope, and when I move the bones, the rope moves, but when I start the cloth simulation, the rope dangles in place and the bones don't follow her