# Attaching a rope (curve or mesh) to two other objects

Tags: mesh, physics

I've already read two threads on this but the instructions given are not clear enough for me.

[image]

i would like to attach the ends of the highlighted mesh, so that animating this part isnt so tedious.

Comment: hello, so have you tried and why didn't it work? also, maybe link the 2 threads

Comment: have you watched this video? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vhicmKyMB-s

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97749/how-to-simulate-a-rope

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192863/best-way-to-attach-objects-armor-to-cloth/192923#192923 and many more: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=attach+rope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is create a long plane, subdivide it, create a group, give it a *Physics > Cloth* with the group as *Pin Group*:

[image]

Create your 2 objects, 2 cubes here (but it can be empties or bones), select a cube, shift select the plane, switch to *Edit* mode, select the same vertices as the pin group, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> > *Hook to Selected Object*. You can hook to a vertex group of the object if needed. Do the same for the other cube. Put the *Cloth* modifier under the *Hook* modifiers:

[image]

Create your pipe object, hook it as well, give it a *Surface Deform* with the plane as *Target*, click on *Bind*. The *Surface Deform* modifier must be under the *Hook* modifiers:

[image]

Make the plane invisible, move the cubes:

[image]

Comment: moonboots, ill paypal you 10 USD when this project is done, if you want it. thank you!

Comment: ah ah no it's ok  ;)   so does it work correctly?

Comment: yes it's working =)